# On click of the back button I want to give a alert box in android using Phone Gap

Tags: android, html, cordova

[image: This time of alert should show]

on click of the back button from the android phone

```
function load() { document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, false);function backKeyDown() {console.log("PhoneGap Ready!");}}
```

I have done this code but still not working Only Back button is not working

Comment: yes? and? what is your problem? where is the error? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are waiting for the "deviceready" event:

```
function load() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDevReady, false);
}

function onDevReady() { 
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, false);
}

function backKeyDown() {
   console.log("PhoneGap Ready!");
}
```